# How to wait until user permissions, to get location coordinate in Geolocator to load a Google map?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am trying to load a google map from getting the current user location.

When I signup (firebase) for the first time it will ask for location permission, then only this exception occurs. 
(Not having this when I sign in, later after the first signup)

This is my  Geolocator and location plugin in pubspec.yaml

```
geolocator: ^4.0.2 version
location: ^2.0.0
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

as official example said you should check permission first. Like this

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return FutureBuilder<GeolocationStatus>(
    future: Geolocator().checkGeolocationPermissionStatus(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<GeolocationStatus> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (snapshot.data == GeolocationStatus.denied) {
        return const PlaceholderWidget('Access to location denied',
            'Allow access to the location services for this App using the device settings.');
      }

      return Center(.... your code)
```

You can find full examples here https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/tree/develop/example